# Regex for find command to match files with a non-empty file extension

Tags: regex, find

I have a series of files that I want to clean up that are .log files that have been rotated. Examples:

```
error.log
access.log
error.log-2016-02-05
access.log.1
debug.log
debug.log--2
```

Regex is matching all of the log files with:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*.log.*'
```

**How can I only match ONLY the files that have characters after *.log?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the last occurrence of `.*` with `.+`.

- `*` matches 0 or more instances of the previous character.
- `+` matches 1 or more instances.

You also need to escape the `.` before `log` with a `\`, otherwise it will match any character rather than just a literal period.

In summary, use this:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*\.log.+'
```

A few other adjustments might also be useful:

- you probably don't want to match files with empty filenames, so you should also switch the first `.*` to a `.+` as well (Thanks, Jan!).
- you probably don't want to allow files with file extension `.log.` (a single . character after `.*log`), so you should switch the final `.+` to `\..+`.

This would give you the final command:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.+\.log\..+'
```

Comment: Just a [regex101.com demo](https://regex101.com/r/xB4oE0/1) to visualize your approach. I'd even change the first `.*` to `.+?` as otherwise filenames like `.log.123` would be matched as well. Nevertheless, +1.